# Why is this happening in c?

Tags: c

```
void xstrcpy ( char *t, char *s );

void main(void ) {      
    char source[ ] = "Sayonara" ;
    char target[20] ;
    xstrcpy ( target, source ) ;   
    printf ( "\nsource string = %s", source);
    printf ( "\ntarget string = %s", target ) ; 
}

void xstrcpy ( char *t, char *s ) {  
    while ( *s != '\0' ){
        *t = *s ;    
        t++ ; s++ ;
    } 
    *t = '\0' ;
}
```

this code gives output:

```
source string = Sayonara 
target string = Sayonara
```

But when I change `char target[20];` to `char target[8];`, it gives:

```
source string =  target string = Sayonara
```

When I change `char target[20];` to `char target[4];`, it gives:

```
source string = nara 
target string = Sayonara
```

When I change `char target[20];` to `char target[3];`, it gives:

```
source string = nara 
target string = Sayonara
```

Why does the source value change, and target becomes array having size of string?

Comment: Any hosted environment expects an integer return value from `main`.

Comment: Please format your code. It's a total mess at the moment that nobody will want to sift through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your target is shorter than required, it overwrites whatever data following it. In particular, when you make it `8`, it overwrites with terminating zero the beginning of the source. When you make it `4`, it overwrites source with the tail of the source string.

This is what's happening. Though this behaviour is not guaranteed, of course, being undefined.

Comment: Thanks Michael,i got it. when i put another char array in between target and source array declaration,source array printed perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but generally you should prevent access to array elements beyond allocated size. You can not reliably tell what's going on past the array's end.

Answer (score 1):

Since target is allocated on the stack, when you copy overflowing data to this array it **overwrites the code following it**. Don't do that, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's still undefined behaviour writing past the end on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

There is no array bound check, if data overflow happens the behavior is undefined!